# Entity with List<T> property isn't updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

The following code does not work as expected. While `item.ActiveEntries` updates and persists after the context is disposed, `user.ShoppingCart.Cart`. Also, both properties are defined as `virtual List<CartEntry>`.

```
using (var context = new LocabalSqlContext())
{
    var user = Auth.GetUser(context);
    var item = context.Items.First();
    var entry = new CartEntry()
    {
        Item = item,
        Quantity = 3,
        LastRefresh = DateTime.Now
    };
    item.ActiveEntries.Add(entry);
    user.ShoppingCart.CartEntries.Add(entry);
}
```

Comment: Where's your `SaveChanges()` call?

Comment: I'm sorry. `SaveChanges()` is called in the `Dispose()` method of `LocabalSqlContext`.

Comment: did you try savechanges before dispose.  You can also try context.GetValidationErrors() before SaveChnages to see what is going on.

Comment: any reason for doing the save inside dispose ?  what about cancel scenarios ? I find that an unusual approach.

Comment: It was a quick fix for us. We're hoping to get it back out. Calling the constructor with `false` sets it to not save during dispose. I'll check out the `GetValidationErrors()` and report back Thursday.